# Data retreving from two tables depending on other column data

Tags: vb.net

here i have the company name combo box.. where user sekects the name..
i want the company name to be displayed in the grid... but as per the table there is a company code column only....

i should display table division data with company name in company table 
there is company code common for both the tables...

i have done this till now.. but getting errors...

```vb
Private Sub btnDivUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  
       System.EventArgs) Handles btnDivUpdate.Click

    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source")
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("update tblDivision set tblCompany.CompanyName='" & 
         cmbDivComName.Text & "',tblDivision.Description1='" & txtDivDesc.Text & "',     
         tblDivision.DivSeq='" & txtDivSeq.Text & "', tblDivision.CreatedBy ='" &           
         txtDivCreatedBy.Text & "', tblDivision.CreatedDate ='" & 
         txtDivCreatedDate.Text & "', tblDivision.LastModifiedBy ='" &   
         txtDivLastModifiedBy.Text & "', tblDivision.LastModifiedDate ='" & 
         txtDivLastModifiedDate.Text & "' JOIN tblCompany ON tblDivision.CompanyCode = 
         tblCompany.CompanyCode where DivisionCode ='" & cmbDivCode.Text & "' ", con)

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("select * from tblDivision", con)
    Dim da2 As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd2)
    Dim ds2 As New DataSet()
    da2.Fill(ds2,
       "tblDivision")
    DataGridDivision.DataSource = ds2.Tables(0)
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

can any one help.........

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Ugh. This will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Not my downvote, though. Everyone has to run into this sometime.

Answer (score 1):

You need two separate sql statements to do this, because you can only write changes to one table at a time. Fortunately, you can send them both as part of the same execute command and transaction. While we're at it, we'll bring your `SELECT` statement into the fold, and fix the sql injection vulnerability and the potential denial of service issue. The resulting code will be a bit longer than what you had, but it will be *simpler* to follow and maintain, in spite of the length, and it will be much safer:

```vb
Private Sub btnDivUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles btnDivUpdate.Click

    Dim sql As String = _
        "BEGIN TRANSACTION t1;" & _
        "UPDATE tblDivision " & _
          " SET Description1= @Description" & _
          "  , DivSeq= @Sequence" & _
          "  , CreatedBy= @CreatedBy" & _
          "  , CreatedDate= @CreatedDate" & _
          "  , LastModifiedBy= @LastModifiedBy" & _
          "  , LastModifiedDate= @LastModifiedDate" 
          " WHERE DivisionCode= @DivisionCode; " & _
        "UPDATE tblCompany" & _
          " SET tblCompany.CompanyName= @CompanyName"
          " FROM tblCompany" & _
          " INNER JOIN tblDivision ON tblDivision.CompanyCode = tblCompany.CompanyCode" & _
          " WHERE tblDivision.DivisionCode= @DivisionCode; " & _
        "COMMIT TRANSACTION t1; " & _
        "SELECT * FROM tblDivision;"

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)

        'I had to guess at column lengths in here
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = txtDivDesc.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sequence", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(txtDivSeq.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = txtDivCreatedBy.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreatedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = CDate(txtDivCreatedDate.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastModifiedBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = txtDivLastModifiedBy.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastModifiedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = CDate(txtDivLastModifiedDate.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DivisionCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = cmbDivCode.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 60).Value = cmbDivComName.Text

        con.Open()
        Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dt.Load(rdr)
        End Using
    End Using

    DataGridDivision.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```